# Sign in to my app via Twitter/Facebook/Google and recognize user in Chrome Extension

Tags: django, authentication, oauth, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

I'm running a Django app, and I'd like to make a Chrome extension to allow users to post content. My users can sign in via Twitter, Facebook, and Google (via `python-social-auth`). I presently do not require accounts to have passwords, so there's no way to log in outside of the oAuth2 methods. How can I authenticate users in the Chrome extension to allow them to post?

The workflow would be something like this:

1. Install Chrome extension
2. Authenticate with my site, which has no password-based user accounts
3. Interact with my API (w/ authentication also via separate oAuth2 consumer, presumably)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to read the user's session cookie from my site's domain and interact with my API w/o a problem.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your solution? What if you have usernames and passwords in django-allauth, how do you authenticate users with a Chrome extension?